# Why are the leaves on my draecana marginata dropping

Tags: leaves, dracaena

I bought a draecana a few weeks back and the leaves were all facing up, but in the past few weeks the leaves have slowly started to droop.

The soil was slightly wet when I purchased it so it didn't need watering. I did water it a week or so later as the soil was dry.

I live in Dubai and I don't use AC due to having problems with my sinuses.  I do allow air to come into the apartment for a few hours every morning from 6 - 9:30.

The past week the temperature has just shot up and the weather we expect in May we are having now. It has hit 40 degrees in the past few days.

The plant isn't in direct sunlight. I am a little lost in what to do as I do not wish for it to get worse. Or is it actually fine?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a draecana marginata for my 4 yr son to learn to care for a plant. I've never seen them with their leaves as upright as you have described.
Your plant currently looks as healthy as the plant that I bought from the store.

Our poor plant experienced more stress as it was not taken care of at the quality level that you are caring for your plant. As with many plants, as the plant ages, the bottom few leaves may dry up some, droop much more significantly and/or turn yellow or brown on the edges. That happened to us a few times. I would teach my son to gently pull those leaves off- they are weakened and would likely fall off if given enough time. The plant will then make new healthier leaves which will grow from the central portion of the group of leaves.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for the reply it's good to realise it is healthy , however some of the actual branch where the leaves spurt put from have started to bend . The issue I find is the inconsistency on sites where they state it needs bright light but not direct,  it doenst need much water , it does etc.